# how check / search datastore events logs in Vsphere?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

after re-registration VMs a realized that one DS is missing.
How can search effectively DS in logs ?
Looks that I need 1 month old logs.

on host I found only 7 days old logs
and via Vcenter Events GUI... looks that this tool is not very user friendly, I see only 1st 100 events per page, and looks that search is working only on 1st page.

```
cd /scratch/log/
# ls -la vmkernel*
-rw-------    1 root     root        558839 Aug  2 10:32 vmkernel.0.gz
-rw-------    1 root     root        559327 Aug  2 01:58 vmkernel.1.gz
-rw-------    1 root     root        556458 Aug  1 17:24 vmkernel.2.gz
-rw-------    1 root     root        560263 Aug  1 08:51 vmkernel.3.gz
-rw-------    1 root     root        554233 Aug  1 00:17 vmkernel.4.gz
-rw-------    1 root     root        560878 Jul 31 15:43 vmkernel.5.gz
-rw-------    1 root     root        555154 Jul 31 07:11 vmkernel.6.gz
-rw-------    1 root     root        553861 Jul 30 22:37 vmkernel.7.gz
-rw-------    1 root     root       9533277 Aug  2 18:26 vmkernel.log
```